# Regex: must start with 'id-' however can't equal but may start with 'id-bitcoin'

Tags: java, regex

I have been using the following Regex to match IDs on [this site](http://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/views/all/) (via JSoup):

```
(?!id-bitcoin)(id-)
```

This Regex is meant to match all instances of `id-someName`, that doesn't equal `id-bitcoin`.

However I realized that it will not match (for example) `id-bitcoindark`.

So now I need to find a regex that will find all instances that start with `id-` and aren't, but may start with, `id-bitcoin`.

Some examples:

`id-bitcoin`   < shouldn't match

`id-ripple`    < should match

`id-litecoin`  < should match

`id-bitcoindark` < **should** match

Big thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this regex with word boundaries:

```
\bid-(?!bitcoin\b)
```

Comment: In 10 minutes, i'll accept this at the correct answer. Thank you very much. But 1 quick question, it is supposed to be `?!` not `?`?

Comment: Yes it should be `?!`, I had a typo (fixed).

Answer (score 1):

Ironically, you need to add `$`:

```
id-(?!bitcoin$)\w+
```

Comment: This will match 'id-bitcoin ', which might or might not be a problem for the scraper. Thumb's up for the $ though! :)

Comment: @folkol adding $ made cents :) p.s. interesting point about he space - added some word chars too

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(^id-.*)([^bitcoin])
```

Tested using

http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html